# Is a type-level annotation always inherited by public methods of that type?

Tags: java, annotations

Is it always the case that the following

```
public interface Foo {

  @MyCustomAnnotation
  void bar();

  @MyCustomAnnotation
  void bar2();
}
```

Is equivalent to

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
public interface Foo {
    
  void bar();

  void bar2();
}
```

Or does it depend on how the annotation is defined? In other words, are class/interface-level annotations always inherited by methods of that type (as long as the method isn't also marked with this annotation)?

Specifically, if I define the annotation above as

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
}
```

Will methods inherit this annotation from the surrounding class/interface?

Comment: It is not "inherited". It all depends how the annotation is evaluated. Please keep in mind that annotations on their own do not have any effect other than providing meta-information. Either a annotation processor (at compile-time) or a snippet of code (at execution-time) evaluates the annotation and does something based on the metainformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *never* the case that they are equivalent unless the library interpreting the annotation specifically decides to treat the type-level annotation as a default (e.g., Spring's `@Transactional`). Even then, it is entirely up to the code written in the library whether a combination of class-level and method-level annotations result in combination (`@RequestMapping`) or replacement (`@Transactional`) of definitions.